# Overflowing variables in c?

Tags: c, malloc, overflow, fgets, exploit

Given this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *password;
  unsigned int *uid;
  
  printf("enter password: ");
  password = (char *)malloc(0x10);
  uid = (unsigned int *)malloc(0x08);
  *uid = 1;
  fgets(password,0xa0,stdin);
  printf("uid: %d\n",(unsigned long)*uid);
  if (*uid == 0) {
    puts("you are logged in as admin");
  }
  else {
    puts("you are logged in as user");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The prompt is to try to find a way to get it to output the uid as 0. I've found the answer involves inputting any string exactly 31 characters in length. I understand this has something to do with the null character at the end of the string overflowing into the uid, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how this happens. malloc() is allocating 16 bytes for password and 8 bytes for uid, and fgets() is attempting to place a maximum of 160 characters into the password. 16 + 8 = 24 bytes but a 31 char string would be 31 bytes with a 32nd byte being the null character. What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: You only allocated 16 bytes with `malloc()`. If you enter more than 15 characters with `fgets()`, undefined behavior will result.

Comment: You never initialized the memory that `uid` points to, so accessing `*uid` also causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Why do you think it would ever output the uid as 0? The terminating null in the password is just a single byte, but `int` is usually at least 4 bytes. There's also no guarantee that `malloc()` will allocate `password` and `uid` anywhere near each other in memory.

Comment: Trying to get specific results when you're causing undefined behavior is futile.

Comment: Are you taking a course or doing an exercise in exploiting defects in programs? And you are trying to craft input that overflows a buffer and causes specific output? If so, that is highly dependent on the situation, including the compiler, the specific source code, and the compilation options. Where the `uid` object lands relative to the `password` object may depend on the `malloc` implementation, but the compiler might also optimize it away since it can see from the source code that `*uid` “ought to be” 1, so it can just change `printf("uid: %d\n",(unsigned long)*uid);` to `puts("uid: 1");`.

Comment: Also using `%d` to print an `unsigned long` is incorrect. `%d` is for `int`. `%lu` is for `unsigned long`. Is that intentional?

Comment: The prompt for this excersise was to find how to break the function and gain the "admin" uid without modifying the code. Entering a 31 char string consistently gets me the correct answer, I just felt dumb for not understanding exactly why that was.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this is an exercise on exploiting defects

Comment: Why it is has to do with where `malloc` happens to arrange memory. That is not specified in the C standard, is generally not specified in the documentation for the C implementation, and is not evident in the source code, so there is no reason you ought to know easily how much data has to be entered to get the desired result, or whether it can be gotten that way at all. Figuring out how to do it requires either experimentation, looking at the code generated by the compiler and the code that implements the standard library, or examining the executable.

Comment: Course material that left you to this without explaining all of this background is likely not good material to learn from.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so what you're saying is that the answer can only be found by analysis of the output from the compiler?

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate your input, I guess I never really understood the question myself.

Comment: It's worse than that. Since you're using `malloc` you have to examine its implementation. Most buffer overflow exploits use local variables, not dynamic allocation, because the behavior is much more predictable.

Comment: @GarrickLyng: It is a combination of the object code output by the compiler and the implementation of `malloc` and possibly other factors.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` doesn't (usually) allocate two consecutive blocks of memory, because (most) `malloc`-allocated memory blocks have bookkeeping information before and after them. Since `malloc` must return "suitably aligned" memory, the minimum total size of the malloc overhead after one block and before the next one is the maximum alignment for any fundamental object; most x86 libraries consider this alignment to be 16 even though no fundamental object has an alignment that strict. In common `malloc` implementations, this overhead is eight bytes before and eight bytes after. (It typically contains some flag bits and the actual size of the allocated block.)

The weasel words above are because the internal implementation of `malloc` is in no way specified by the C standard, and indeed varies considerably between different `malloc` implementations. In an ideal world, I suppose, all programs would be 100% portable and we would never think of breaking into an implementation to see how it accomplishes its work. But exploits are not portable, and if you want to know how they work -- whether for black-, white- or purple-hatted activities -- you'll have to dirty your hands with actual implementation details. I don't condone any sort of exploitation, but understanding how compilers and standard libraries work is interesting in its own right, and probably hones your programming intuitions.

So, returning to your code. Since it is running very soon after the initialisation of the memory management system, it's likely that consecutive malloc calls will return more or less adjacent memory. Since each allocated block has 8 bytes before and after it, it is somewhat likely that `uid` will be exactly 32 bytes after `password`: 16 bytes allocated to `password`, 0 padding bytes, 8 trailing overhead bytes, and 8 leading overhead bytes.

On the architecture you are most likely using, integers are stored "little-endian", so the first byte in `uid` -- that is, the byte whose address is lowest -- is the low-order byte, which contains 1. Reading 31 bytes + a NUL terminator into `password` will overwrite the low-order byte of `uid` with a 0. Hence the result you see.

The `fgets` will also overwrite `malloc`'s bookkeeping information, which may cause problems later on. In this particular code, the damaged blocks are not free'd, and so the malloc bookkeeping blocks are never examined. But if you were to attempt to free the blocks, you would either trigger a malloc consistency check or you would cause malloc's internal view of memory to be corrupted; either way, sooner or later something bad would happen.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate this breakdown. Ultimately I'm working on projects like this one to help me design more robust code and have a better eye for blunders like undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *defined* behavior that would result in the program presented printing the uid as 0.  (Indeed, the `printf` format is incorrect for the type of the second argument, so the program's behavior is undefined regardless.)  But if we assume that the expected response to the exercise is that inputting any password of exactly 31 characters yields the desired result, then we might speculate that that effect arises from the following combination of assumptions, implementation characteristics, and manifestations of undefined behavior:

- The machine represents integers in memory in little-endian format, so that the least-significant byte resides at the lowest address (common, but by no means universal).
- The implementation's pointers afford a flat view of the memory space (typical, but not guranteed).
- `malloc()` will reliably allocate the space for `uid` such that it starts exactly 32 bytes after the start of the memory allocated for `password` with respect to that memory space (not altogether improbable under the specific circumstances, but in no way guaranteed).
- The system will not detect overflow of the `password` space (typical, but not guaranteed).

Under those conditions, if you input a password of exactly 31 characters, *as determine3d by the 32nd character being a newline*, then `fgets` will start writing them into memory at the address specified by `passwd`.  Because it was told that that space is large enough to accommodate `0xa0` characters (as opposed to the actual `0x10` characters), it might continue writing bytes past the end of the allocated space until eventually writing the newline (which `fgets()` does transfer when it thinks space is available for it) as the 32<sup>nd</sup> byte, at an address that we can imagine being represented by `password + 31`.  Finally, `fgets()` -- we hypothesize -- writes a null byte to terminate the string at the next position, which happens to be the first byte allocated for `uid`.  Because the integer stored in `*uid` has value 1 represented in little-endian form, that overwrites its only non-zero byte with a zero byte, such that thereafter reading `*uid` from memory yields the value 0.

I emphasize that neither the C language nor any particular implementation of it that I know promises that result.  I am furthermore confident that in practice, it would play out differently on many implementations.  And I cannot promise that the above correctly explains what is actually happening in *your* C implementation.  It is, however, a plausible explanation of one way that the effect you observe is being produced.